# Your experience on using configuration & VCS tools

Tags: version-control, configuration-management

I am doing my study's final year project and would like to do a little survey here. The topic is about configuration management and version control system for an industrial product (such as a piece of software, a furniture design, a car engine or even an aeroplane design etc...)

1.) What is you field of expertise (IT, engineering, manufactuing etc..) and what is the configuration management and version control system you use (previously or now) for your work?
2.) What is your opinion/comment (good, bad, what is it lack of or what can be improve etc...) about them? Much appreciated if you can include some real life examples for your opinion/comment.

Of course you are welcome also if you simply wish to share your thought on the current configuration management and version control system in market.
Thanks all in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for your input.
Is there anyone else have experience using configuration management system for industrial product other than software?

ps: I am sorry if SO can only ask question reqarding software related issue but not others

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the Computer Security field, and we use Perforce. It's pretty good for my needs (I'm a Development Manager) - supports easy branching (not as easy as git, but we don't really need something that flexible), the conflict resolution is pretty good, and the command-line tool lends itself to easy scripting.

The downside is the price - from what I hear, P4 is rather pricey (I'm not involved in purchasing, so I don't know the specifics), and I don't think we're getting anything out of perforce that couldn't be found in an open-source solution (again, I look at git). However, we're a large (>1000 person) software development company, we have offices scattered across the world, and perforce is quite entrenched already, so I don't think we'll be switching any time soon.

In the past, I've used Perforce at a different company and Visual Source Safe (awful!).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a good topic for SO...  In any case:

For developing software we're very happy with git.   If your developers are particularly inexperienced or you have "people who need graphical user interfaces" on your team you might be happier with Subversion.

For tracking our system configuration files (DNS, puppet, nagios, that sort of thing) we use Subversion.

Comment: Actually I don't really means for tracking of "configuration files". I am just using the terms "configuration management" for a general idea of version control which can be for hardware product such as a car engine design.

For example, it can be the various configuration of a car engine design whereby you track the different part needed. Subsequently, you might derived a new car engine design based on the orignal version but with variantion of the parts used. I am more interesting on this kind of configurtation which I think some of the CAD software implemented.

Answer (score 0):

About tracking configuration files with version control system: that is not what VCS are for, but for example for Git there are many tools built on top of Git to manage configuration files: **IsiSetup**, **etckeeper**, and other that can be found e.g. on http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools web page.

Comment: As my comment to BJorn, I don't really means to track configuration files :)

Answer (score 0):

This question might extend to less technical focused, semantic markup and generative designs.

Software and Systems Technologies:

## [[D]VCS'es](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software)

- Git is, by far, the most popular DVCS in open source these days. [Thanks Linus!]
- Mercurial [Hg] is functionally almost identical to Git due to history.
- Bazaar [bzr] is another DVCS similar to Git and Mercurial.
- Subversion [SVN] is a CVS common in small-to-large businesses.
- Perforce [P4] and ClearCase are common is giant, traditional organizations.
- Fossil is for the "ultra-cool" startup daring to be different.

## Older VCS'es

- CVS [not to be confused with CVSNT] is a predecessor to SVN.
- RCS is the non-networked predecessor to CVS.

## System Configuration Management

- Cfengine 2 and 3
- Puppet
- Chef
- MCollective
- Chef knife
- fabric

## Software Configuration Management

- Java

  - Ivy
  - Maven (mvn)
  - pom.xml
- Python

  - pip
  - setuptools
  - virtualenv
- C/C++

  - autotools
- Ruby

  - capistrano
  - rake
  - rubygems
  - rvm
- Haskell

  - cabal
- Erlang

  - epm
- Node.js

  - NPM